# How can I access a GET request in CAKEPHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How can I access a GET request in CAKEPHP ?

If I am passing a variable in the url

```
http://samplesite.com/page?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

Should I use $_GET or $this->params to get the values in controller?
What is the standard in CAKEPHP ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The standard way to do this in Cake is to use `$this->params`.

```
$value1 = $this->params['url']['key1'];
$value2 = $this->params['url']['key2'];
```

According to the CakePHP book, "the most common use of $this->params is to access information that has been handed to the controller via GET or POST operations."

See [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html#the-parameters-attribute-params).

Comment: Thanks Dude... Shall i avoid to use $_GET in cakephp?

Comment: @cakephp.saint Yeah, I typically don't access $_GET or $_POST directly when i'm working in Cake.  I just updated my answer with a link to the manual.

Answer (score 28):

In CakePHP 2.0 this appears to have changed. According to the documentation you can access `$this->request->query` or `$this->request['url']`.

```
// url is /posts/index?page=1&sort=title
$this->request->query['page'];

// You can also access it via array access
$this->request['url']['page'];
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html

Comment: Thank you. Rescue comes sometimes no in the first, but the second post :D

Comment: Or even $this->request->query('page'); instead of $this->request->query['page'];

Comment: Is it needed:  if ($this->request->is('get')){ $this->request->query['page'];}

Comment: Or can I just: $this->request->query['page'];

Comment: `$this->request->query` worked for me in my client's old project which was in cakephp 2.4 version. Thanks Code Commander :)

Answer (score 8):

And now that we have CakePHP 3; you can still use `$this->request->query('search')` in your views.

And in CakePHP 3.5 +  you can use
`$this->request->getQuery('search')`

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-parameters

Answer (score 2):

According to CakePHP 4.0.2

> $this->request->getQuery()

will give you the whole query strings as an array

and for specific query

> $this->request->getQuery('keywords')

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/request-response.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only to get URL params,

```
$this->request->pass;  //Array of all parameters in URL
```

Answer (score 0):

According to CakePHP documentation 
[Query String Parameters](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/request-response.html)

```
// URL is /posts/index?page=1&sort=title
$page = $this->request->getQuery('page');

// Prior to 3.4.0
$page = $this->request->query('page');
```

To access the all keys from URL You have to  use

```
$data = $this->request->getQuery();
echo "<pre>";print_r($data ); die('MMS');
```

**Output**

```
<pre>Array
(
    [key1] => value
    [key2] => value
    ...........
)
```