# cakePHP: access $this->request->data through view files (information passed by controller)

Tags: cakephp, view, controller

How to access `$this->request->data` passed in by controller  inside Views? e.g. variable defined by `$this->set('sample')` inside controller can be accessed by `$sample` inside view and .ctp files. How can I access values stored inside `$this->request->data` through view files?

Comment: I'd suggest that you read the docs before asking such questions. **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#View::$request**

Comment: For a cakePHP 3 solution check http://stackoverflow.com/a/31679836/22470

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakerequest) says that `$this->request` is available within Controllers, Views, and Helpers. So you can access it using `$this->request->data` in your view. If you wanted to give it a shorter name, you could set it to something in your controller:

```
$this->set('requestData', $this->request->data);
```

If tyour view only needs a couple of variables, it may be clearer to unpack the request data in your controller and pass them in directly. This would also be better [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns); if you refactor your application later, you won't have to update the view as long as you pass in those parameters too:

```
$this->set('name', $this->request->data('name'));
$this->set('age', $this->request->data('age'));
```

(Note that I'm using the [CakePHP `data()` method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-post-data) to access these properties; you don't have to treat it as an array).